# Job DSL script reference

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

For now, using a gradle wrapper as a test tool a build gives me following log:

```
Processing provided DSL script
Warning: (script, line 22) concurrentBuild is deprecated
```

It doesn't provide any information which script is meant. Therefore i can not allocate the lines. It should look like this:

```
Processing DSL script build/jenkins-job-dsl/jobs/dsl/section/buildpipelines/BuildPipelines.groovy
Warning: (BuildPipelines.groovy, line 22) concurrentBuild is deprecated
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use disableConcurrentBuilds
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options